# innerText.includes() stripping newlines

Tags: javascript, newline, innertext

I'm making a dictionary website for [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban). It's relatively simple: load a premade `<div id="entries">` and move all the entries with an `innerText` containing the search query into `div#results`.

#### The issue

There are no entries containing the string `u.a`, yet a result for one exists, whose `innerText` contains `u\n\na`. The `innerText` in `search(query)` seems to be removing newlines, even though (a) it shouldn't do that (b) running `document.querySelector("#results .entry").innerText.includes("u.a")` returns `false`.

#### Attempted fixes

Running `.replaceAll(/\n+g/, " ")` on the `innerText` before finding the search query in it

#### Relevant code

```js
const id = (x) => document.getElementById(x);
function search(query) {
    var i = 0;
    var results = [];
    for (const entry of id("entries").childNodes) {
        const text = entry.innerText.replaceAll(/\n+/g, " ");
        if (text.includes(query)) {
            console.log(text, query, text.includes(query));
            results.push(entry);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return [i, results];
}
// ... lazy-loading function ...
var timer;
id("search").addEventListener("input", function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    id("status").innerHTML = "<span>.....</span>";
    const q = id("search").value;
    let page = 0;
    if (observer) {
        observer.disconnect();
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (q.length != 0) {
            const s = search(q);
            const l = String(s[0]);
            const res = s[1];
            const pad = "<span>" + "0".repeat(5 - l.length) + "</span>";
            id("status").innerHTML = pad + l;
            id("results").innerHTML = "";
            // ... lazy-loading + url updating ...
        } else {
            id("status").innerHTML = "";
            id("results").innerHTML = "";
            page = 0;
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Whitespace in HTML content gets collapsed (so you won't _see_ newlines even if they're there), unless you specifically _force_ that behaviour by using CSS that sets the white space handling for your element to be that of preformatted text. S

Comment: Right, but I thought it collapsed all `\s+` into one space? not zero?

Comment: Only _for rendering purposes_. The textContent still has all your newlines, you just won't _see_ them unless you set the white-space behaviour to show them. So: if you don't want them, explicitly remove them before setting your textContent, or if you do want them, you'll have to include them in your `includes` pattern.

Comment: I added `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `.entry` CSS and switched to `textContent` but it's somehow still happening - what did you mean "include them in your includes pattern"?

Comment: `includes()` looks for exact matches, it's not doing pattern matching. So if the string you're searching has spaces or newlines, you have to have them in the search string.

Comment: You might want to use a regular expression match rather than `includes()`.

Comment: What @Barmar said. The `textContent` property is still just the literal string, if that's as string with  `u\n\na` in it, then only ```.includes(`u\n\na`)``` will return true. The string is what it is, and the browser _renders_ the string based on CSS, which means it may be _presented_ with whitespace turned onto a single space, but the _data_ still has all your newline and extra spaces and tabs etc. etc. in them and if you want to do string matching, you'll have to include those.

Comment: If only `.includes("u\n\na")` should return true, why is `.includes("u.a")` also returning true? I am admittedly confused here

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding one space character to my database-generating program. lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).